# How do I find out What Query was sent to SQL Server using Linq To Entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I want to find out what query string was sent to sql server from using Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137712/sql-tracing-linq-to-entities